# Alternative to LAG() in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, calculation, cumulative-sum

DISCLAIMER: New in SQL Server programming

I'm currently working on a calculation in SQL that I cannot figure out.

Basically it's a calculation where you have an opening balance, some calculations that depends on the opening balance and a closing balance. The final result of the table should be as follows:

```
| Employee  | ROWN |Balance_year1 | O_balance | calc   | C_balance |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| Emp1      |  1   | 1000         | 1000      | 20     | 1020      |
| Emp1      |  2   | 1000         | 1020      | 20.4   | 1040.4    | 
| Emp1      |  3   | 1000         | 1040.4    | 20.808 | 1061.208  | 
| Emp2      |  1   | 2000         | 2000      | 40     | 2040      |
| Emp2      |  2   | 2000         | 2040      | 40,8   | 2080,8    |
| Emp2      |  3   | 2000         | 2080,8    | 41,616 | 2122,416  |
```

Until now I wrote the code as follows:

```sql
WITH table1 AS (
    SELECT
       *
     , [O_balance] = LAG([C_balance], 1, [Balance_year1]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Employee] ORDER BY [ROWN] ASC)
    FROM dataset
),
table2 AS (
    SELECT 
       *
     , [calc]      = --Some calculations that depends on the [C_balance] from the row before
    FROM table1
)
SELECT 
    *
  , [O_balance]
  , [calc]
  , [C_balance] = [O_balance] + [calc]  
FROM table2
```

My problems regarding the table is:

1. The `[C_balance]` is not calculated when used in the first CTE, so it cannot run. (Invalid column name `[C_balance]`)
2. The `[C_balance]` is not calculated correct when it is used in the `[calc]`.

I imagine that you can either calculate the table row-after-row or save `[C_balance]` in a variable an update it throughout the run, but idk?

I hope that one of you guys can help me out - the struggle is real :-) Thanks!

Comment: Is there a column `[C_balance]` in `dataset`?

Comment: Nope, all the columns i made after the * are added columns for the calculation

Comment: Then what do you expect from `LAG([C_balance], 1, [Balance_year1])`?

Comment: Do you have an alternative? I've tried a lot of different thing, but i thought that this failed example would be the best to show you to give you an understanding of the problem :-)

I can tell you the fact that there are languages where you can look one row up as the peek-function i Qlik

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want with a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select employee, rown, balance, balance as o_balance, balance * 1.02 as c_balance
      from dataset
      where rown = 1
      union all
      select d.employee, d.rown, d.balance, cte.c_balance, cte.c_balance * 1.02
      from cte join
           dataset d
           on cte.employee = d.employee and d.rown = cte.rown + 1
    )
select *
from cte;
```

I'm speculating a bit on what your calculation is, but this works for the data you have provided.

Comment: Thanks for your help - It did help regarding to the problem i posted. 

I didn't explain quiet well in the first attempt (sry --> guess i'm rookie). Can you check out my changes in the table? Thanks!

Comment: @xxxKryptoPiratenxxx . . . Normally, you should ask a *new* question.  In this case, I figured that you actually intended to do this by employee and the modification is rather trivial, so I updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

This looks like a running sum problem to me (and the question is tagged as such, so I'm going to go with it). First, the code:

```
with d as (
    select * from (values
        ('Emp1',  1   , 1000         , 1000      , 20     , 1020      ),
        ('Emp1',  2   , 1000         , 1020      , 20.4   , 1040.4    ), 
        ('Emp1',  3   , 1000         , 1040.4    , 20.808 , 1061.208  ), 
        ('Emp2',  1   , 2000         , 2000      , 40     , 2040      ),
        ('Emp2',  2   , 2000         , 2040      , 40.8   , 2080.8    ),
        ('Emp2',  3   , 2000         , 2080.8    , 41.616 , 2122.416  )
    ) as x(Employee  , ROWN ,Balance_year1 , O_balance , calc   , C_balance)
), c as (
    select *, balance_year1 + sum(calc) over (partition by employee order by rown) as myCalc
    from d
)
select *, C_balance - myCalc
from c
```

I'm using common table expressions here only for ease of use - the first to get your data in a consumable format, the second to show an intermediate step. The final query shows that my calculation and yours come up with the same answer. The "magic" is the `sum(calc) over (partition by employee order by rown)` bit. In reasonably modern versions of SQL (introduced in 2012 iirc, but maybe even earlier), you can do that to get a running sum.